# As anyone tried to use SOAP service through dedicated Automator action?

Tags: macos, soap, automator

I'm currently trying to build a simple Automator processus that would use public Flickr SOAP API to fetch URL of current interesting photos. (this is only 1st step, but the mandatory one)

The goal is to use SOAP action.

Had pretty hard time to find any kind of example on how to use this action with existing services.

Any help is welcome :)